# What NuGet packages are needed for OAuth 2 only

Tags: oauth-2.0

Assume I already have a user data store that I am happy with (Usernames, Hashed passwords, etc ...) and all I want to add is the ability to issue and process JWT tokens and refresh tokens. What would be the minimal NuGet packages that would be needed?

I realize ASP Identity is a proven system, I would just like to figure out what is needed to issue OAuth 2.0 JWT tokens using Microsoft's NuGet packages. Assume that I already have the code to properly validate a username and password and I can determine validated or not validated.